# How to install a specific version of OCaml on MacOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I am trying to install version 4.02.3 of [OCaml](https://ocaml.org/) on MacOS 10.14.6 with the following command

```
brew install ocaml@4.02.3
```

but I get an error

```
Error: No available formula with the name "ocaml@4.02.3"
```

I need that specific version to compile `unison` with that specific version, so I can use `unison` between a Linux box (where I cannot install a different version of `ocaml` and the Mac).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the git history to obtain the formula for OCaml 4.02.3

Go to the local directory where formulas are stored:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
```

Look at the history of the OCaml formula:

```
git log ocaml.rb
```

It appears that the last commit of version 4.02.3 is commit `3cdad82334496ca9fe8d8fb37`.

Check out this commit:

```
git checkout 3cdad82334496ca9fe8d8fb37
```

By default, Homebrew make an update before an install, so you have to specify to not update before the install:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install ocaml
```

Check that you have the right version with:

```
ocaml -version
```

When finished, don't forget to go back to the master branch, in the `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula` directory:

```
git checkout master
```